# Proving $n(n-2)(n-1)^2$ is divisible by 12

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I want to show that $n^4 - 4n^3 + 5n^2 -2n$ is divisible by $12$ whenever $n>0$.

I reduced this to $n(n-2)(n-1)^2$. My approach has been to check divisibility by $3$ and $4$.
In both cases, squares are always congruent to $0$ or $1$. So
\begin{align*}n^2 &\equiv_3 0, 1 \\ \implies (n-1)^2 &\equiv_3 n-2, n-1\end{align*}
Given $-1\equiv_3 2$, then $(n-1)^2\equiv_3 n-2$ or $(n-1)^2\equiv_3 n-1$. But now I'm stuck here.

I know the polynomial is made up of a product of 3 consecutive numbers, so either two of them are even and one odd, or two of them are odd and one even. When I made the assumption $n$ is even, then $n-1$ is odd and $n-2$ is even, eventually landing at $n(n-2)(n-1)^2 \equiv_4 n(n-2)$ but so far nothing helpful has come up.

What am I missing?

Comment: $(n-2)(n-1)n\cdot (n-1)$ is divisible by $3$. If $n$ is odd, then $(n-1)$ is even and thus, $(n-1)^2$ is divisible by $4$. If $n$ is even, $n$ and $(n-2)$ are even and thus divisible by $4$.

Comment: @Lex_i Regarding divisibility by $3$, instead of what you did, note that the product includes $3$ consecutive numbers (i.e., $n-2$, $n-1$ and $n$), as you already stated, so one of those consecutive numbers *is* a multiple of $3$.

Comment: By the first dupe it's divisible by $3$ and also by $4$ being $(\color{#c00}{n(n\!-\!1)})^2\!-2\color{#c00}{n(n\!-\!1})^2$ and $\,2\mid \color{#c00}{n(n\!-\!1)}\,$ (or examine odd/even cases  as in the 2nd dupe) $\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n$ is even, $(n-2)$ is also even, and $n(n-2)$ is divisible by 4

If $n$ is odd, $(n-1)$ is even, and $(n-1)^2$ is divisible by 4.

Comment: Very simple explanation, +1

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $(n,12)=1.$  We use Euler and lil' Fermat.

$$n^4-4n^3+5n^2-2n\equiv 6-6n\equiv 2(n-1)\pmod {2^2},$$
and
$$n^4-4n^3+5n^2-2n\equiv 6-6n\equiv 0\pmod 3.$$

So by CRT, using Bezout,  we have $1×4×2×0-1×3×2(n-1)\equiv6(n-1)\equiv0\pmod{12}.$

Suppose $(n,12)\neq1.$  Then either $2\mid n$ or $3\mid n.$

If $2\mid n,$ then if $3\not \mid n$, we are done by the previous calculation and CCRT.

If $3\mid n,$ then $n^4-4n^3+5n^2-2n\equiv 0\pmod3.$  So we're done by CCRT.

If $2\not\mid n$, then $3\mid n,$ so we're back to Bezout,  since we have already done the modular arithmetic: $$1×4×0-1×3×2(n-1)\equiv 0\pmod {12}.$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).